wasm file picker created in EM_ASM is not shown in Safari
I am trying to run this ImGui wasm demo and make a file upload like it is described here.
The problem is that file picker created as
EM_ASM(
  var file_selector = document.createElement('input');
  file_selector.setAttribute('type', 'file');
  file_selector.setAttribute('onchange','open_file(event)');
  file_selector.click();
);

is not shown in Safari. Successful execution should open file picker, then after file selection trigger open_file defined in index.html, then it should call load_file defined in main.cpp and finally it should write Received bytes: N in the browser console.
Currently the temporary demo is available here and its source code to reproduce here,
the only thing needs to be done to build it is to define IMGUIPATH in makefile.bat.
What I have tried:

I've checked that the same file_selector creation js works fine if I bind it to the regular html button event handler
tried to change EM_ASM with emscripten_run_script, put console.log after each file_selector statement to be sure all of them are executed - all this log is shown in the browser console but file picker is not shown
after searching a lot I think the most possible explanation I found is this one
and it says "The only possible way to open a FileSelect or Upload dialog programmatically is to use pure JavaScript and a user (client-side) event". I've made an attempt to move that file_selector creation js to js function in html and do EM_ASM of setTimeout with that function - result is the same, does not work in Safari but works in other browsers
tried to use library mentioned in the answer providing this file_selector solution but I am getting some build failures. I am completely new to c/cpp, but I have concerns that this library may help because it contains very similar code.

One more thing I have to note is that I don't have a real mac, I do testing on Windows with browserstack.com, but I don't think it should matter.
